# Is there equivalent API in golang for EVP_DigestVerify openssl api?

Tags: go

I am trying to find equivalent API in golang for below openssl api's.

EVP_DigestVerifyInit 
EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate 
EVP_DigestVerifyFinal

Please provide links or docs if equivalent API available and i am using go version go1.11.4 linux/amd64

Comment: Hey srini, it is going difficult for me to uderstand what are you trying to ask. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Hi Kaushik thanks for the response. Basically i am trying to rewrite some of cpp code to go lang.In that cpp code the following openssl api's used EVP_DigestVerifyInit, EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate, EVP_DigestVerifyFinal. I need an equalent API in go lang. Is it makes sense to you ?